# Can I not let people subscribe to me on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-subscriptions

So Facebook has a new feature which display all your friends activity (even things you wouldn't previously have been notified of (such as "*X liked Y's picture*")) above the chat/messaging bar on the right side of the screen.

I do not like this.

Is there a way I can prevent myself from showing up in this to my friends?

Answer (score 5):

First thing,

> which automatically has everyone subscribed to everyone so anything anyone does whom you're subscribed to (by default all your friends)

**This is false**

There are two subscriptions.

1. Public Subscriptions
2. Friend Subscriptions

Public subscriptions are new. Friends subscriptions were always around in the form of "Hide Stories from this person". (I have confirmed this for some of my subscriptions show as unsubscribed)

So your friends were "subscribed" to you long before the subscriptions feature was officially pushed. If they didn't like your updates all they had to do was

[image: Hide all from friend]

[image: Hidden stories]

And this *auto-magically* lets them unsubscribe from your updates.

**For the ticker**

> If you hide someone from your News Feed entirely by unsubscribing from them, they won’t show up in ticker.

http://facebook.com/help/?faq=266468286709084

For limiting what shows on other users' tickers you can change your privacy settings.

Image sources: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/unhide_a_hidden_facebook_friend_in_your_newsfeed.html

Comment: I was unclear.  Please see my (hopefully) clarifying edit.

Comment: It's not about them not showing up in my ticker, I don't want to show up in *other people's* tickers. I want to know if it's possible for me to make this happen from my end.

Comment: That's what I thought which is why I asked here.  :) Oh well, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

All friends are subscribed to you by default, and there doesn't seem to be a way to force someone to unsubscribe without blocking them entirely, much less mass-blocking people. If your friends don't want your updates, they can [narrow down](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=188147907920585) what updates they get.

You can read more about the subscribe button [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=246210718757459).